# Is it possible to debug an external ant task?

Tags: java, ant

I have an ant script which calls an external ant task:

```
    <taskdef name="runStoriesAsEmbeddables" classname="org.jbehave.ant.RunStoriesAsEmbeddables"         
    classpathref="project.classpath" />

     <runStoriesAsEmbeddables includes="**/Ant*Stories.java" ignoreFailureInStories="true" 
     ignoreFailureInView="false" 
     systemProperties="story.path=.,qr.host=*,qr.port=*" generateViewAfterStories="true" />
```

And I want to use -Xdebug to launch JVM on an unix box.
I read several doc which using "jvmarg value="-Xdebug"" in "java" task but for external task...I don't know how to use it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the ANT_OPTS environment variable before running Ant. Assuming you use the Bash shell:

For Java 1.4:

```
export ANT_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=y
```

For Java 1.5 and later:

```
export ANT_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=y
```

Run your Ant script and then attach to port 5005 with your debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works!  I just want to mention another thing: we can launch a program by using `<java><jvmarg></jvmarg></java>` inside ant script but it means this class must contain Main method because `<java>` launch a new jvm and it needs an enter-point.  But for my example, it doesn't contain main method because it only is an inherited ant task.  For this kind of situation, the only chance to use -Xdebug is when launch ant.  We need to export ANT_OPTS as Chad mentioned and ant will use it when it launch.